# Calling objects in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to simplify my code. The code is meant to draw some diagonal lines on a graph. The following is the original code:

```
x = np.linspace(-5,6,50)
y1 = x
y2 = x+1
y3 = x+2
y4 = x+3
y5 = x+4
y6 = x-1
y7 = x-2
y8 = x-3
y9 = x-4

plt.plot(x,y1, linewidth=3, color='k')

plt.plot(x,y2, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y3, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y4, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y5, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y6, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y7, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y8, color='b')
plt.plot(x,y9, color='b')
```

I'm trying to simplify the last few lines with the following 'for' loop:

```
for i in np.arange(2,10):
    plt.plot(x,yi, color='b')
```

the `i` is not recognized by Python. What would be the correct way to do this? Perhaps a `lambda`? I'm really not sure.

Comment: Putting your `y` values in a list is probably simplest, then you can `plt.plot(x,y[i], color='b')`

Comment: Related to your attempted solution: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341) If you went that route you would want to use a list. But I think [gmds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596113/4518341) makes more sense in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```py
plt.plot(x, x, lw=3, color='k')

for i in range(-4, 5):
    if i != 0:
        plt.plot(x, x + i, color='b')
```